# Testcafe and Soft Assertions

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, assertion

My tests have multiple assertions. Currently, if one assertion fails, a whole test stops.
But I need to get all assertion errors instead of stopping at the first one.
Does Testcafe have soft assertions mechanism?

Answer (score 2):

At present, TestCafe doesn't have this feature. At the same time, I saw several similar requests with different scenarios.
Would you please describe your idea in greater detail?

Feel free to request your feature on GitHub using this template: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=feature_request.md